# Generalized File Upload for Browsers IE8,IE9, Chrome, safari, firefox

Tags: jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, jquery-file-upload

Well i have searched on net about getting generalized solution for clientside fileupload plugin but i am failed to get any proper and general solution that can work with IE8, IE9, chrome, safari and Firefox. If there is anyone who has proper and general solution for that than please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get any error using the plugin? Are you trying to do any cross-domain upload? The plugin works well with those browsers and versions you mentioned.

Comment: I have used JQuery file upload, but it is not working in IE8, also used bootstrap upload, ajaxFileUpload but i got the same problem, in IE8 it is not working

Comment: Have you been able to catch any error? On IE8 you can debug your scripts files to pinpoint the problem.